# Gridview Add Header Row, Merge Columns

Tags: asp.net, gridview, header

I have a simple GridView with a header and a footer, etc.  What I need to do is to add another header row - above the first - so that I can merge two column headers into one, from a grouping perspective....

What I have Now:

Col1    Col2

----      ------

test     test2

What I need:

### Cols

Col1    Col2

-----     ------

test     test2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL doesn't work anymore. Here's the new URL :
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/Merge_Header.aspx